# General questions on terminology for probability and statistics.

Tags: probability, statistics, terminology

As someone self-studying college-level mathematics, I am currently reading an introductory book on probability and statistics. However, I am a bit perplexed by the following terms, as they appear to be used interchangeably from my point of view.

**Could someone help me clarify my misconceptions, and also inform me if there's anything I have missed? This would be much appreciated.**

#### Terminology alongside my current understanding of them

1. probability mass function -
   function that returns the chance of a random variable taking on some value (for discrete only)
2. probability density function -
   function that returns the chance of a random variable taking on some value (for continuous only)
3. probability distribution -
   a general term that describes both #1 and #2
4. cumulative distribution function -
   a general term that describes both #1 and #2 aggregated over some range

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probability mass function is simply a function which returns a probability between $0$ and $1$ that events in the sample space will occur. For example, consider an unfair coin being flipped.

Say it has a $60\%$ chance of landing on heads, and $40\%$ chance of landing on tails. Lets call our sample space: $\Omega = \{H, T\}$. Where $H$ denotes a head, and $T$ denotes a tail.

Our probability mass function then is a function of the form $f:\Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$,  this can be written as:

$ f(x) = \begin{cases} 
      0.6 & x= H \\
      \\
      0.4 & x = T 
   \end{cases}$

Notice that $f(H) + f(T) = 1$

In fact, in general we must have: $$\sum_{x\in \Omega} f(x) = 1$$

This corresponds with the fact that something must happen.

As for probability density function, this is similar concept, except in this case we have a continuous sample space. In this case we have a function of the form $f:\Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, however in this case $\Omega$ is continuous. For our purposes we could take $\Omega$ to be $\mathbb{R}$.

In this case imagine the function $f$ is $f(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-x^2/2}$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$

Here we have an important distinction from the probability mass function. A particular output of the function $f(a)$ does NOT mean that $a$ has $f(a)$ chance of occurring. Rather it is a relative measurement, and gives its likelihood of occurring as compared to other values of $f(x)$. The probability of any particular value $a$ of occurring is in fact $0$. This may seem a bit strange but it is a result of measure theory and has to do with the size of infinity.

A probability distribution is just a blanket term for either of the first two mentioned.

The cumulative distribution function is essentially a function of the form $F: \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ where for any $x \in \Omega$, $F(x)$ is the probability that an event less than or equal to $x$ will occur.

For example imagine we are rolling a fair six sided die. If $F$ is the cumulative distribution function, then $F(4)$ is the probability that anything less than or equal to a $4$ will be rolled. So if $f$ denotes the probability that a certain number will be rolled, then $F(4) = f(1) + f(2) + f(3) + f(4) = \frac{2}{3}$.

This is particularly useful when talking about probability density functions, the reason for which was alluded to earlier. In a probability density function the probability that any particular outcome of an experiment will occur is $0$. Imagine that the function we mentioned before $f(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-x^2/2}$ represents the probability that a random number generator will choose the number $x$.

In this case if we have a cumulative distribution function called $F$, then $F(x)$ denotes the probability that the number chosen is less than or equal to $x$. This is something useful that can give us a non-zero probability.

The function $F(x)$ would be written as: $$ F(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{x} f(t) dt$$

where $t$ is just a dummy variable of integration.

Comment: Presumably, you mean that $f(4)=2/3$ in your dice example.  Normally capital letters are used for cumulative distribution functions and lower case letters for pdf's and pmf's.

Comment: Yes, you are right I changed the calculation. I suppose I could change to a conventional upper case and lower case if that was desired.